# How do I add a whitespace character when reading from a file to a Linked List?

Tags: java

I read characters from the file and add them to  `LinkedList<Character>`

```
String text = fileReader.getText("myText.txt");
List<Character> characters = new LinkedList<>();
characters =  text.chars().mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In the file, the letters are arranged in a line:

```
A
B
C
;
1

/
```

and after the `1` there is a space character, but when iterating it is skipped.

How to make sure it is added?

Comment: what encoding is the file and what encoding is your reader using?

Comment: @MaxG standart UTF8

Comment: @Omegon Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. You are talking about "iterating", but there are no loops anywhere.

Comment: What is `fileReader`? What does the method getText do? How are you checking the the space character is actually skipped? As an aside, you're throwing away your `new LinkedList<>();` when you reassign `characters`.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work.

Input file:

```
ABC;1 /
```

Program code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final String fileName = "C:/myText.txt";

    final String text = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName)).stream().map(n -> String.valueOf(n))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

    final List<Character> characters = text.chars().mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char) i))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));

    for (final Character next : characters)
    {
        System.out.println("Next char: ".concat(next.toString()));
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Next char: A
Next char: B
Next char: C
Next char: ;
Next char: 1
Next char:  
Next char: /
```

Comment: `final List<Character> characters = text.chars().mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char) i)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));` suffices.

Comment: Ah, that is better. Thank you.